# How to use ImpersonatedCredentials on Google Dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-iam

Dataflow allows to [specify a User Managed Controller Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#specifying_a_user-managed_controller_service_account), via `--serviceAccount` option.
Besides that, I would like to [impersonate a service an account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials) to interact with GCP resources before job submission. One example use case would be to use the Beam SDK's FileSystems API to check for some GCS object metadata.

How can I instruct [`beam.sdk.io.FileSystems`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileSystems.html) and `storage.StorageOptions` to use `ImpersonatedCredentials`?

Some example code, that would run outside GCP Dataflow workers:

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems;

    // list blobs in a GCS path
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(
      bucketName,
      BlobListOption.currentDirectory(),
      BlobListOption.prefix(directory));

Resource resource = FileSystems.matchNewResource(path, false)
```

By impersonating a Service Account, I mean [using short lived SA credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials), as for example:

```
creds = ImpersonatedCredentials.create(ServiceAccountCredentials.getApplicationCredentials(), 
          "example-service-account@example-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
          Collections.emptyList(), // list of delegates
          Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only"),
          3600);
```

Comment: Have you used any documentation or try sth before?

Comment: I am thinking you can write your own ParDo, in which you use the credential to check GCS metadata.

Comment: I am also looking for references for documentation.

Comment: I don't see where the ParDo fits here. The question is about checking GCS metadata before job submission (Pipeline.run()).

Comment: Could you explain a bit how does the GCS metadata in pre-job-submission step work with the pipeline? If you need to feed those metadata to pipeline, sounds like you can do it within ParDo. Also I did some search but didn't find relevant documentation about it.

Comment: The least you can do is to ask you question in user@beam.apache.org. Such that if it not supported yet, devs in Beam community should be aware of such feature request.

Comment: Struggling with this! Can you please share the solution here?